# Setting the width of a UITableView equal to the maximum cells' width inside of it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new to iOS development so please excuse my question if the answer to it is a straightforward one.

I would like to set the width of the UITableView equivalent to the width of the maximum cell inside of it. Please refer to the attached image for further explanation.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: How are you setting the cell size currently? Also why are the cells left aligned.

Comment: The textLabels inside the cells are fixed Top, Bottom and Left to the Cells. And I am relying on intrinsicContent for the textLabels to be sized properly in terms of their widths.

Comment: What I would do is before I set the `dataSource` I would precalculate the sizes of the cells, and find the largest one after doing so.

Comment: I am also stuck with exact problem, was big relief after seeing your question. Could you please let me know how did you fix it @devJo? Its been already 2 days I am struggling with it :(